# What is the notation for a set with a variable size?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm trying to write the definition "Set $S$ has between $0$ and $n$ elements (inclusive)" concisely in set notation.

For the case when $n=4$, I would write the definition as
$$S=\{\}\vee \{a\}\vee \{a, b\}\vee \{a, b, c\}\vee \{a, b, c, d\}$$
but this obviously doesn't scale to arbitrary $n$.

Comment: $0\le|S|\le4,$ where $\mid S \mid$ denotes the cardinality of $S$

Comment: ^ No more concise way than that.

Comment: Are you trying to write a definition in the language of set theory?  If so, you need quantifiers to make your $n=4$ definition work.

Comment: That works well for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write $0\le|S|\le n$ to indicate that the set $S$ has between $0$ and $n$ elements (inclusive).   $|S|$ denotes the [cardinality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of the set $S$.

Comment: To simplify still further, you don't actually need $0 \leq \vert S \vert$.